# the string line isn't printing in the output screen.whats the error

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d= scan.nextDouble();
        String a= scan.next();
        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + a);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is happening? What are you typing, and what's the result?

Comment: (I ran your code entering "10 10.5 foo" and then hitting return, and it was fine...)

Comment: Please clarify the problem, I [cannot reproduce it](https://ideone.com/Xppp3L). Make sure your code is properly saved and compiled. Make sure the console is large enough to see all the text.

Comment: @Butiri Dan That happens when you use `scan.nextLine()` which consumes a line terminator, not `scan.next()` which does not.  This code works completely fine running it in all new lines or running it all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

**nextDouble**() does not consume the new line itself so the next token returned will be an empty string. Thus, you need to follow it with a scan.**nextLine**().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Insert an int: ");
    int i = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Insert a double: ");
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Insert a string: ");
    String a = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Inserted string: " + a);
    System.out.println("Inserted double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Inserted int: " + i);
}
```

and the output is:

```
Insert an int: 45
Insert a double: 7.7452
Insert a string: Hello World

Inserted string: Hello World
Inserted double: 7.7452
Inserted int: 45
```